# Running Windows bash as shell in Emacs (Spacemacs)

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, spacemacs

I'm trying get Spacemacs (i.e., Emacs) to use the Windows subsystem for Linux bash shell as the shell.

I've added `(setq explicit-shell-file-name "c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe")` to my .spacemacs configuration file, but when I enter:

```
SPC SPC ansi-term
```

and answer yes, it returns:

```
Spawning child process: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `.spacemacs` file, you should be sure `shell` layer is enable, and then put this statement in your `.spacemacs` file : 

`'((shell :variables shell-default-term-shell "c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe"))`

After that, you could call your shell by keybinding `SPC '`

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration to .spacemacs is correct. Just use `SPC SPC shell` instead of `SPC SPC ansi-term` to get the bash shell within Spacemacs for Windows.